# TextMate has stopped recognizing comments

Tags: textmate

My textmate suddenly stopped recognizing comments in code and the shortcut for commenting out code (Command + /).

I have found Comments in the Bundle Editor for HTML, but it doesn't look like I can set an activation key for it or anything.

Does anyone have any experience with this part of TextMate?

cheers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe it went out of scope?  Doesn't matter what caused it, it's easy enough to fix.

- Open your **Bundle Editor**
  *ctrl-option-cmd-B*
- Make sure that the Menu button at the
  top left-hand side of the Bundle
  Editor displays Show All
- If it doesn't then click the up/down
  arrow and change it so that does
- Scroll down until you find the
  *Source* bundle
- Click the arrow to the left of
  *Source* to display the Bundle contents
- looking at the Source Bundle items
  with green "C"s next to them, find the item
  called *Comment Line/Selection*
- Click *Comment Line/Selection*
- In the upper right-hand corner of the
  Bundle Editor, click the *Settings*
  button
- Next to *Activation*, select the menu
  item *Key Equivalent*
- Whatever is in the text box to the
  right, replace it with **cmd-/** (with
  your cursor in the text field, press
  the keys "cmd" and then "forward
  slash"
- Verify that the item **Scope Selector**
  text area is blank--nothing should be
  in there
- Exit the Bundle Editor, Restart
  TextMate, open a new editor window
  (cmd-N) then enter *cmd-/* to verify
  that it's working

This command is not limited by scope so it will work in any context/environment/language, **but** because it is not limited by scope it can be overridden by a Bundle-specific comment command (e.g., a comment command in the HTML Bundle, so, if after you've followed those steps, it's still not working, you just need to find that Bundle-specific comment command and either fix it (using the steps above as a template) or then use the steps above as a template) or deleting it.

While you're at it, you might as well fix the command in your HTML Bundle:

from your Bundle Editor, scroll down to the HTML Bundle then click on the *Comment* item (you said in your Q, you had located it). Click the *Settings* button on the upper right-hand corner, and verify that *Activation* is *Key Equivalent* and *cmd-/* is in the adjacent text box. Next verify that *Scope Selector* is *text.html*

Comment: awesome! thanks for the detailed walk through. Turns out my Source Bundle was filtered, which was easy to figure out after following your instructions.

Thanks!

Comment: What if it's not letting me enter cmd+/ it looks like there's something else using that keyboard shortcut or something. can't figure it out. thanks!